# INDEX AND MATCH function: Hurdle in creating dashboard

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

[image]

The formula used:

```
=INDEX(in!D:D,MATCH($B$1,in!$B:$B,FALSE) * MATCH(B$3,in!$C:$C,FALSE),1)
```

The same not giving the desired output.For Year 1 of AAL, not sure how 78787 (for year 2 and year 3) instead of 5822 shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your formula to:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(in!$D:$D,MATCH(1,($B$1=in!$B:$B) * (B$3=in!$C:$C),0)),0)
```

- ($B$1=in!$B:$B) * (B$3=in!$C:$C): The result of each operation will be booleans. When you multiply them, the result will be either `0` (not found) or `1` (found).
- MATCH(1,($B$1=in!$B:$B) * (B$3=in!$C:$C),0): Finds the row where both criteria are correct.
- =IFERROR(INDEX(in!$D:$D,MATCH(1,($B$1=in!$B:$B) * (B$3=in!$C:$C),0)),0): If found display the result. If not, display `0`.

[image: Results]

Comment: Your solution worked. However, clueless why my earlier function did not work. Worse, it was showing wrong values.

Comment: @TechcosecLimited Your formula was for example for Year 1 of AAL, finding the match for AAL which was 2 and Year 1 also 2. But then multiplying them 2 * 2 =4. So, the result was in D4: 78787. The error carried on for the other others values as the multiplication of rows and columns indexes giving the incorrect values (results). If you break down the thow MATCH of your formula into different cells to check the result (or use Evalute Formula), you will  see what I am talking about.

Comment: The syntax of MATCH function is: MATCH(lookupvalue, lookuparray). In this case, MATCH(1,($B$1=in!$B:$B) * (B$3=in!$C:$C),0):  I understand lookup value of 1 is if Boolean logic true. It will help if you explain the operation of MATCH function here as this seems to be different from usual syntax.

Comment: @TechcosecLimited ($B$1=in!$B:$B) will find values in column B that equals to B1 (your lookup value). The results will be an array of Trues and Falses. The same for (B$3=in!$C:$C. When you multiply both arrays, you will get an array of 0s and 1. There will be only one 1 as there is only one AAP for Year1. So MATCH(1,($B$1=in!$B:$B) * (B$3=in!$C:$C),0) returns that 1 value.